# HTML-CSS position problem with div

Tags: css, html

I got a little problem and nothing I test seems to work.

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top_parent">Top_background
        <div id="top">Top_Picture</div></div>
    <div id="content">Here comes random stuff<div>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">Footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#top_parent {
    background:#f00;
    height:100px;
}

#top{
    background:#0f0;
    float:right;
    position:relative;   
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
}
#content{
    top:-50px;
    background:#00f;
    <!--   position:relative;-->
    height:100px;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
#parent{
    background:#000;
    height:350px;
    width:100%; 
}

#bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background:#ff0;
    bottom:0px;
    <!--position:absolute; -->
    <!--position:relative; -->
}
```

Now my problem is, the footer won't get under the `parent` div, it stays in the content area. What am I doing wrong?

jsF link: [my source](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2X29/10/)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As a note, comments in CSS are delineated with `/*` and `*/`, not `<!--` and `-->`. Usually a CSS parser will simply ignore a line that has an error in it, but better safe than sorry, imo.

Comment: ah right, well my last website was around 2 years ago so i simply forgot :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not closed this div:

```
<div id="content">Here comes random stuff<div>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="content">Here comes random stuff</div>
```

You could see this easily if you indented your divs:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="top_parent">Top_background
    <div id="top">Top_Picture</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">Here comes random stuff<div> <!-- Can see the problem -->
</div>
<div id="bottom">Footer</div>
```

Comment: grrr, i could smash my head on the wall. why didnt i see this. your right it works fine if i close the html tag right.
Thx for fast answer!

Comment: @Auro - like I said, if you use clean indented markup, things like this are easy to spot.

Comment: well the problem is i have dyslexia and i could have cleaned it up right and maybe i still wouldn't have see it :D but thank!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you copy-pasted or if this is a typo when you posted your code, but this line:

```
<div id="content">Here comes random stuff<div>
```

Should have a closing `</div>` tag at the end instead of that opening `<div>` tag. If that's actually your HTML, then it would not be grouping the divs the way you want/expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top_parent">Top_background
        <div id="top">Top_Picture</div></div>
    <div id="content">Here comes random stuff<div>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">Footer</div>
```

You didn't close div parent, nor content

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top_parent">Top_background
        <div id="top">Top_Picture</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Here comes random stuff</div>
    <div id="bottom">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Interpreting that you want the "bottom" div inside the "parent", else:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top_parent">Top_background
        <div id="top">Top_Picture</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Here comes random stuff</div>
</div>    
<div id="bottom">Footer</div>
```

Also, in your css you should enable the position:relative for #content div, else the top parameter won't work.
Try if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to position footer after the content divs you have to float content divs first and then add clear:both css command to the footer. So your tree sould look like this:::

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div><br clear="all" /><div class="footer"></div>
```

For this example your css should be as following:::

div.wrapper{
   width:80%;
   position:relative;
   margin:0 auto;
}

div.left{
   float:left;
   width:60%;
   background:green;
   height:200px; /*height only for testing so you could see the result*/
}

div.right{
   float:right;
   width:30%;
   background:red;
   height:200px; /*height only for testing so you could see the result*/
}

div.footer{
   clear:both;
   height:40px;/*height only for testing so you could see the result*/
   background:yellow;
   width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out that "bottom" attribute in the #bottom rule?